# JButton changing color when pressed

Tags: java, colors, click, jbutton, actionlistener

I kept getting the same error: "cBtn cannot be resolved to a variable"

```
    public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame("Butt1");
        JButton btn = new JButton("Change color");
        frame.add(btn);
        btn.setBackground(cBtn);
        frame.setSize(250, 100);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }
    Color[] colors = new Color[] { Color.red, Color.orange, Color.yellow, Color.green, Color.blue,
            new Color(075, 000, 130), new Color(128, 000, 128)};
    int color;
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        Color cBtn = (colors[color++ % colors.length]);
    }
}
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: `cBtn` is a local variable -> only accessible in the `actionPerformed` method. If you want to access it from another method, make it a field, or pass it as a parameter (impossible if you're dealing with swing overrides for instance)

Answer (score 0):

This should do the trick, if you turn your local variable `cBtn` into a field, accessible everywhere within your class: (I didn't touch the rest of the code, for it's not part of your current problem)

```
 public class Main {
    private Color cBtn;
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame("Butt1");
        JButton btn = new JButton("Change color");
        button.addActionListener(new ActionListener() { 
            @Override 
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) { 
                cBtn = (colors[color++ % colors.length]); 
            }
        }
        frame.add(btn);
        btn.setBackground(cBtn);
        frame.setSize(250, 100);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }
    Color[] colors = new Color[] { Color.red, Color.orange, Color.yellow,     Color.green, Color.blue,
            new Color(075, 000, 130), new Color(128, 000, 128)};
    int color;
```

}

Comment: I tried this solution however still need to make the field static which makes changing of color impossible.

Comment: make both of them static then! Seems like it wouldn't be of trouble since `colors` is instanciated once and for all. But if you need more help regarding this code, you're gonna have to give a little more context, or create a new question to explain what you need (why would it need to be `static`, for instance)

Comment: when I tested this solution button press did not changed the background color of the button according to my assumptions. So to my understanding the problem lies in declaration of the field as static. Do I see it wrong?

Comment: Well, as I told you it's a completely other matter. Given the `actionPerformed` method, I'm assuming you're using Swing, and if that's the case, something is wrong: you can't just declare an `actionPerformed` method, you need to override it for a dedicated component (listener? I don't remember^^), so it has nothing to do with the original compilation problem

Comment: I copied it into eclipse, changed button to btn, etc and encountered even more obstacles.

Answer (score 0):

Decided to redo it:

```
public class Main extends JFrame {
        private JButton btn;
        public Main() {
        super("Butt1");
        setLayout(new FlowLayout());

        btn = new JButton("ChangeColor");
        add(btn);
        ServClass serv = new ServClass();
        btn.addActionListener(serv);
    }

    Color[] colors = new Color[] { Color.red, Color.orange, Color.yellow, Color.green, Color.blue,
            new Color(075, 000, 130), new Color(128, 000, 128) };
    int color, click1 = 0;

    private class ServClass implements ActionListener {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            btn.setBackground(colors[color++ % colors.length]);
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Main run = new Main();
        run.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        run.setSize(250, 100);
        run.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

It mostly according to this tutorial:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=3RQOikbGGUM

thx HBo for Y/assistance!